# Managing multiple forms in MVC3 project and validating conditionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, validation, postback

I have refactored two separate pages into one, and have merged the view model as well.

Now in my project the login and register forms are in the same page in a tabbed view.

The problem I have is with the validation.
The first form has two fields that are Required and the other form has 2 other fields that are also Required. If I post the first form, Validation will fail for the other two fields.

I experimented with IValidatableObject but I can't do something like:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (PostPackOrigin == "LoginForm")
        {
            if(Username == "")
             yield return new ValidationResult("Username missing");
            if(Password == "")
             yield return new ValidationResult("Password missing");
        }
        if (PostPackOrigin == "RegistrationForm")
        {
            if(Name == "")
             yield return new ValidationResult("Name missing");
            if(Email == "")
             yield return new ValidationResult("Email missing");
        }
    }
```

Or something like that. 
How can we detect the origin of the postback, or is there another way to handle the validation?

Many thanks